# Is it possible pass non-managed arguments/bean args along with @value and/or spring managed bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I think this is not possible and possibly breaking the Spring-managed bean concept. Basically, right now I am initializing beans (multiple beans of the same class in some cases based on constructor args) from the @SpringBootApplication class. e.g.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App  { 
  @Autowired
  private Registry registry;
  
  @Autowired
  private Gson gson;
  
  @Bean(name="AtlantaClient")
  public Client atlantaClient() throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
      var address = "ws://" + atlantaIP + ":" + atlantaPort;          
      Client client = new Client(address, gson, registry);
      client.connect();   
      return client;
  }
  
  @Bean(name="MumbaiClient")
  public Client mumbaiClient() throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
      var address = "ws://" + mumbaiIP + ":" + mumbaiPort;        
      Client client = new Client(address, gson, registry);
      client.connect();   
      return client;
  }  
}
```

So rather than specifying `Registry` and `Gson` as `Autowired` here in App class, can I somehow use/inject directly in `Client`'s constructor along with address??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.. what does "*can I somehow use/inject directly in Client's constructor along with address*" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if that's what you want, but you can specify such bean dependencies directly as method arguments in the @Bean methods:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    @Bean(name = "AtlantaClient")
    public Client atlantaClient(Registry registry, Gson gson) throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
        var address = "ws://" + atlantaIP + ":" + atlantaPort;
        Client client = new Client(address, gson, registry);
        client.connect();
        return client;
    }

    @Bean(name = "MumbaiClient")
    public Client mumbaiClient(Registry registry, Gson gson) throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
        var address = "ws://" + mumbaiIP + ":" + mumbaiPort;
        Client client = new Client(address, gson, registry);
        client.connect();
        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not following what you are suggesting? Could you add more colors?

Comment: I can't add colors in the code block (at least not that i know), but i'm referring to the method header: `public Client atlantaClient(Registry registry, Gson gson)` and `public Client mumbaiClient(Registry registry, Gson gson)`

Comment: Re: `you can specify such bean dependencies directly as method arguments`, I don't see where you have specified dependencies. It is the same code I posted.

Comment: No, if you look closely, you didn't have any method arguments, since you had the autowired objects as fields on class level. I put them as method arguments (that's what i understood what you wanted. If it's not what you wanted, you should specify that in more detail in the question)

Comment: Ohh, okay gotcha. But I was thinking something else when I put a question. Let's say `Client`'s constructor is `Client(String address, @Autowired gson, @Autowired registry)`. So `gson` and `registry` are being managed by Spring and I should just be required to somehow specify/pass `address`. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help. In that case, I think this is the best approach.